# WebAPI modelbinding to complex type containing list of complex types - from body

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, complextype

I've read and tried [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/18/mvc-style-parameter-binding-for-webapi.aspx) and keep going around in circles.

**Edit**: The client is sending the model it received, the server builds the complex types as per the classes listed below and sends it to the client, the client sends the exact same model back but model binder will not bind to it.

Using AngularJS posting a complex type containing a list of complex types to my web api. The post body is as follows:

[image]

The complex type I'm trying to bind to is:

```
public class AttendanceSelectTModel
{
    public List<AttendanceChildSelectTModel> CA { get; set; }
    public List<AttendanceChildSelectTModel> CI { get; set; }
    public bool SignIn { get; set; }

    public AttendanceSelectTModel() { }

    public AttendanceSelectTModel(List<Person> ppl)
    {
        CA = new List<AttendanceChildSelectTModel>();
        CI = new List<AttendanceChildSelectTModel>();

        foreach (Person p in ppl)
            if (p.Status == Status.SignedIn)
                CA.Add(new AttendanceChildSelectTModel(p));
            else
                CI.Add(new AttendanceChildSelectTModel(p));
    }
}

public class AttendanceChildSelectTModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public string ImgURL { get; set; }

    public AttendanceChildSelectTModel() { }

    public AttendanceChildSelectTModel(Person user)
    {
        Name = user.FirstName;
        PId = user.PersonId;
        ImgURL = user.ImgURL;
    }
}
```

Can you point me in the right direction? Is what I'm trying to do even possible or can I not bind to a list of complex types?

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone else is having the same issue, the answer seems to be know. I'd love to know otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Model Binder is not able to bind to a complex type containing a list of complex types. My solution was to break the complex type down to a flat list of variables, not great because I was using angularJs. The other solution would be to extend model binder class and handle the data binding manually.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the statement 'Unfortunately the Model Binder is not able to bind to a complex type containing a list of complex types'?  I'm trying to achieve the same thing and am surprised that it isn't possible in WebApi, given that it's completely supported in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I only reached that conclusion after many weeks of research and not finding anything. I have found couple of scenarios where the Model Binder class was extended to handle custom functionality, if you'd like I can dig those up for you.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you shared your findings.